# Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError (hostname "mybucketname.s3.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com" does not match the server certificate)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm having an issue with calling .head_object using Amazon AWS SDK Version 2.  I'm working in a Rails project, using Figaro to set my environment variables and have named them as AWS SDK expects: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, etc.

Here's the code I'm using to try to call head_object:

```
direct_upload_url_data = %r{\/(?<path>uploads\/.+\/(?<filename>.+))\z}.match(direct_upload_url)
direct_upload_url_data_string = direct_upload_url_data.to_s
s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new
direct_upload_head = s3.head_object(
    bucket: ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
    key: direct_upload_url_data_string
  )

  self.image_file_name     = direct_upload_url_data[:filename]
  self.image_file_size     = direct_upload_head.content_length
  self.image_content_type  = direct_upload_head.content_type
  self.image_updated_at    = direct_upload_head.last_modified
```

As you can see I'm trying to access a specific file's metadata.  I've checked the regex and it seems to be returning the correct key which is something like "uploads/{uniqueID}/image.jpg" The error is coming on the line where I am trying to call head_object.  The error I'm getting is

```
Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError (hostname "mybucketname.s3.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com" does not match the server certificate)
```

That path is not what I see when I go to my bucket, I see https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mybucketname so I'm not sure if that's the reason I'm getting the error.  I've connected to this bucket before using AWS SDK Version 1 so I know my access and secret keys are working fine.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Does your bucket name have a `.` in it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a wrong region name for your amazon bucket. 
Try to change "s3-us-west-2" to "us-west-2".

Answer (score 0):

I'm very sure you've already resolved the issue but for future readers, as tapatun mentioned, make sure your region name does not include the s3 prefix and should read: "us-west-2".

But afterwards, make sure to restart your server, otherwise the old configurations may still remain making you go on a wild goose chase!

Good luck and happy coding everyone!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14399671)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!